# Error: incompatible remote API v5 or earlier

Tags: javascript, remote-access, strongloop

I am trying to run the following command

slc pmctl -C http://abc:def@123.456.78.912:1111 log-dump --follow

and I am getting the following error

Command "log-dump" on "http://abc:def@123.456.78.912:1111" failed with Error: incompatible remote API v5 or earlier

Any help? Suggestion?? Thank you in advance ;)

Comment: What version of `strongloop` or `strong-pm` is running on the server? This error indicates that it is older than the version you are using on your workstation.

Comment: Thank you so much @RyanGraham. You are right. After three days of know what was the error and realised that it was the version of strongloop and node. I also discover that the server also had some problems.